# Small self managed server hosting solutions

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting, web-hosting

I've seen AWS EC2 and similar cloud solutions for enterprise-level hosting, where they give you a virtual machine instance on their servers and you're free to administrate it yourself.

I'm not sure what this is called, it seems like "self managed hosting" is the buzzword here (cloud hosting, maybe). Anyway, I'd like a small instance of one of these for my personal site, so I can run Java, Ruby, Node, Mongo, whatever, on a publically available server that I can configure myself.

Is it reasonable to expect a solution for under $300/year?  It looks like EC2 instances start at around $113/year or $226/year (http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/).  Is this good or bad, and what is this service called, so I can shop around?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions seeking service recommendations are off-topic here ("Is there an affordable solution out there?"), so as this stands it's likely to get closed.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - fair enough, not quite looking for a recommendation, more of a terminology question so I can shop around myself, and to check what price range to shoot for. Edited OP to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are usually referred to as "Virtual Private Servers" or by the acronym VPS.

I've also seen this service called "virtual hosting" or you'll see the phrase "virtual machine" or "virtual server" in the description.  In addition to Cloud providers like AWS, Rackspace and Azure, other hosting providers such as Dreamhost and MediaTemple also offer Virtual Private Servers.

Comment: Thanks, config headaches are what I want :)  I've done quite a bit of work on AWS solutions already in business environments, just haven't applied it to a small-scale problem yet.  It's mostly going to be a sandbox portfolio for various projects/learnings in different languages, so headaches are par for the course.

Comment: @Steve *"on a publically available server without config headaches" "Thanks, config headaches are what I want"* Which will it be? Anyway, service shopping recommendations are off-topic here, unfortunately.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling good point. What I meant in the original post was when a managed hosting solution doesn't allow installation of third-party software, so I have to use Heroku or something to host the code, which is an extra headache. Edited OP to reflect this.